# Cannot add JDateChooser to IntelliJ IDEA palette

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, jdatechooser, jcalendar

I want to add the `JDateChooser` component from [jcalendar](/questions/tagged/jcalendar) to the [designer palette](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/add-edit-palette-component.html) in [intellij-idea](/questions/tagged/intellij-idea); but when I'm adding `com.toedter:jcalendar:1.4` through Maven dependency or JAR, I'm getting an error:

```
class "com.toedter.calendar.Jdatechooser" cannot be instantiated:
index 0 out of bound for length 0
```

Same JAR file works in **Netbeans** GUI editor.

If anyone has an idea of how to add `JDateChooser` in **IntelliJ IDEA** then please share your answer.

**Note:** This is not a duplicate of questions about adding [jcalendar](/questions/tagged/jcalendar) as a library.

Comment: _This is not a duplicate question_ curious: how do you know? did you find any similar question? If so, please add a reference and explain why your context is different :)

Comment: hmm .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69268256/error-add-jdatechooser-to-jpanel-in-jformdesigner-7 shows a similar error (no answer, though) BTW: is the error message above c&p'ed or typed on-the-fly? Just asking, because the spelling of the class name is off ..

Comment: @kleopatra I c&p'ed this error. BTW this is unique because whenever I am trying to add this jar as a component then it shows an error, but when I used this jar programmatically runtime then it works fine. However, I didn't find any similar question and yes, https://stackoverflow.com/q/69268256/12660050 look like but not similar :)

Comment: hmm .. when it's c&p'ed that might hint to the reason: it's looking for _com.toedter.calendar.Jdatechooser_ but the class name is _com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser_ (note the capitalization), isn't it? So could you show a [mcve] that leads to the error?

Comment: Just to be clear: Do you want to add [tag:jcalendar] to the [tag:intellij-idea] GUI editor or just add it as a library dependency.

Comment: @trashgod I want to add to the intellij-idea GUI editor. I don't have any problem to add jcalendar  As a library dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a JPanel and then setting it's layout to borderlayout in Layout Manager.
Then add the add to your Main Form.

JDateChooser dateChooser = new JDateChooser(); //initializing the calendar
jpCalendar.add(dateChooser); //adding the calendar component to JPanel

Comment: format the code into readable item and add steps